# include tag django with a form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Im trying to include a template in another template with django, all works fine if the template that i including has no variables, but when the template has a variable, for example a {{form}} does not render the variables but does render the template:

views:

```
class IdentifiacionsUsuariosView(FormView):
    form_class  = FormProductores
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'propietarios.html'

    def form_valid(self,form):
        productor = form.save()
        return super(IdentifiacionsUsuariosView,self).form_valid(form)
```

template-1.html

```
Hello    
<form action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <p><input type="submit" value="ok"></p>
    </form>
```

template-2.html

```
<div class="span4" id="campo1">
{% include 'template-1.html'  %}
</div>
```

like this, i see "hello" and the submit input but i cant render the form, how can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#reusable-form-templates

Have the template quoted in your code.

```
{% include "template-1.html" %}
```

> If the form object passed to a template has a different name within the context, you can alias it using the with argument of the include tag:

```
{% include "form_snippet.html" with form=comment_form %}
```

Comment: i already did that but nothing happens, from where comes "comment_form" in the docs?

Comment: comment_form is the name of the form object in the context of the outside template. If this is different than the {{ form }} tag of the included template, you need to alias it using with.

Comment: I have edited the question including the views, you can see that my form object is called FormProductores and i did `{% include 'propietarios.html' with form=FormProductores %}` but it does not works

Comment: FormView supplies the form in the context as `form` so my answer does not help you. Sorry I didn't know you were using a FormView. If you just copy the contents of template-1 into template-2 does it work?

Comment: yes, thats works, but template-1 has too many forms, so i think the most effective way to do it is include each template into template-1.html

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do this ?